# Eclipse installing problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse

I am a new Ubuntu user who is running Ubuntu 16.04. After I installed Java I tried to install Eclipse, but it gave me this message although I downloaded it from the official website.

```
Incompatible JVM
Version 1.6.0_45 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.  
Version 1.7.0 or greater is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a newer version of OpenJDK to be compatible with the Eclipse file that you downloaded. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

OpenJDK is a development environment for building applications, applets, and components using the Java programming language.